# sql select - order by but partial part of the field

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

i want to use the order by catid... but i need to use it on the 2 letter of the catid field
this is not working for me: order by mid(catid, 2,3)

what can be the answer?

Comment: Your data structure is wrong if a substring of the data in one field has meaning independent of the value of the field as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your use of [mid](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/mid.php).

```
Mid ("Tech on the Net", 1, 4)   would return "Tech"
Mid ("Alphabet", 5, 2)  would return "ab"
Mid ("Alphabet", 5)     would return "abet"
```

Your second parameter needs to be a 2 at the very least.  Not sure what your catid looks like.